# showing an article based on date it was published

Tags: php

```
<?php
  // Fetching all the Navbar Data
  require('./includes/nav.inc.php');

  $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
  error_reporting(0);
?>

<!-- Article List Container -->
<section class="py-1 category-list">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="headings">Artikel
      <?php
      echo "<h2> $current_date </h2>"
      ?>
    </h2>
    <div class="card-container">
      <?php

        // Article Query to fetch maximum 5 random articles
        $articleQuery = " SELECT category.category_name, category.category_color, article.*
                          FROM category, article
                          WHERE article.category_id = category.category_id
                          AND article.article_date <= {$current_date}
                          AND article.article_active = 1
                          ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5";
        // Running Article Query 
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$articleQuery);

        // Row stores the no of rows in the return data from Query
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        

        // If query has any result (records) => If any articles are present
        if($row > 0) {
          
          // Fetching the data of particular record as an Associative Array
          while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            
            // Storing the article data in variables
            $category_color = $data['category_color'];
            $category_name = $data['category_name'];
            $category_id = $data['category_id'];
            $article_id = $data['article_id'];
            $article_title = $data['article_title'];
            $article_image = $data['article_image'];
            $article_desc = $data['article_description'];
            $article_date = $data['article_date'];
```

i want my news portal to only appear for a given date and not show up before that date. like a scheduled article. so he can display past or current news. in this screenshot, that article was supposed to be published on august 3rd 2023.

is there a mistake with my sql query? any suggestion? [image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? The query itself looks fine, besides the problem that it is highly vulnerable for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date is a textual rather than a numeric field so needs to be quoted ... `<= \"{$current_date}\"`

This gets all posts before or on the current date. Not sure if this was your intention.

Comment: "date is a text field" - are you sure? Usually, one would use a DATE or DATETIME column for a date

Comment: I meant stored as text in the general sense, rather a number, therefore values need quoting. Date and datetime fields can be searched, ordered and manipulated like a char, varchar or text so definitely sit in that camp.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it